# racecondition between put_page and pci_unmap_sg

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on a device driver that includes dma. If I just use `get_user_pages_fast` and `put_page` everything is working. As soon as I add calls to `pci_(un)map_sg` it seems to become racy.

After the test program finishes I *sometimes* get a **BUG**, however i do not always get the **BUG**.

The BUG reads:

```
[ 7202.183324] BUG: Bad page state in process dma  pfn:f20ea8
[ 7202.183327] page:ffffea003c83aa00 count:0 mapcount:-30705 mapping:          (null) index:0xc0054000d3431e41
[ 7202.183329] page flags: 0x2ffff000008000c(referenced|uptodate|swapbacked)
```

And has the following trace:

```
[ 7202.183442] Call Trace:
[ 7202.183447]  [<ffffffff8171e0be>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[ 7202.183453]  [<ffffffff8171aa88>] bad_page.part.61+0xcf/0xe8
[ 7202.183459]  [<ffffffff81155ce8>] free_pages_prepare+0x148/0x160
[ 7202.183463]  [<ffffffff81156651>] free_hot_cold_page+0x31/0x150
[ 7202.183467]  [<ffffffff811567b6>] free_hot_cold_page_list+0x46/0xa0
[ 7202.183473]  [<ffffffff8115c210>] release_pages+0x80/0x210
[ 7202.183478]  [<ffffffff8118b725>] free_pages_and_swap_cache+0x95/0xb0
[ 7202.183483]  [<ffffffff81174c5c>] tlb_flush_mmu.part.56+0x4c/0x90
[ 7202.183486]  [<ffffffff811757d5>] tlb_finish_mmu+0x55/0x60
[ 7202.183491]  [<ffffffff81180c0b>] exit_mmap+0xcb/0x170
[ 7202.183497]  [<ffffffff810646cc>] mmput+0x5c/0x120
[ 7202.183502]  [<ffffffff81069b1c>] do_exit+0x26c/0xa50
[ 7202.183506]  [<ffffffff811bef1e>] ? ____fput+0xe/0x10
[ 7202.183511]  [<ffffffff8106a37f>] do_group_exit+0x3f/0xa0
[ 7202.183515]  [<ffffffff8106a3f4>] SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[ 7202.183520]  [<ffffffff8172ec2d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
```

Are there any additional locks that I have to hold for any of the functions (there is no hint for the pci-dma api, and where I see `put_page` in other drivers there are no locks near it). Is there another point where I could go wrong?

I currently pass the same pointer to `pci_unmap_sg` as the one I used for `pci_map_sg`, which seems ok, after looking at other drivers and use the actual page count rather than the count returned from the mapping for unmapping.

I think I am missing some locking or synchronisation, as [this post](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0501.3/2319.html) might hint, however my understanding of linux memory subsystem is to bad to follow.

Also `[release_pages](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/swap.c#L899)` seems to be an alternative, however I see `spin_unlock_irqrestore(&zone->lru_lock, flags);` in a view paths without a prior lock, do I need to hold the lock before calling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initialized the scatter/gather list wrong, I thought calls to `sg_set_page` would suffice, however an initial call to `sg_init_table` is needed.

Since I found many drivers NOT doing so, AND ldd3 is not mentioning `sg_init_table` anywhere, I figured it might be helpful if I leave this here.